# How to create Redirect URI OAuth2 in C# Console App with Dropbox API?

Tags: c#, .net

I've tried to create a Redirect URI, but seems that it is wrong. Actually, it's my first time trying to work with Dropbox API using .Net and I don't know many things.

As I said, I'm using Console Application in Visual Studio 2017. I wrote the code down below.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Settings.Default.AccessToken))
        {
            this.GetAccessToken();
        }
        else
        {
            this.GetFiles();
        }
    }

    private void GetAccessToken()
    {
        var login = new DropboxLogin("wbjcj6pa94berli", appKey, "https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/info/wbjcj6pa94berli", false, false);
        login.Owner = this;
        login.ShowDialog();

        if (login.IsSuccessfully)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.AccessToken = login.AccessToken.Value;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error...");
        }
    }

    private void GetFiles()
    {

    }
}
```

I've created this Redirect URI in My App on Dropbox's site for Developers.

Redirect URI on Dropbox's WebPage:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I'm getting that MessageBox with "Error..." because, obviously, something is wrong.

Could any of you guys help me with this? Thanks a lot.